# Scrapy is not using MY FilesPipeline, even though I've done all to enable it

Tags: python, scrapy

I was using FilesPipeline for downloading files, but the files got downloaded with a hash in their name, so I decided to change that. I used [this instructions](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#topics-media-pipeline-override), but the spider doesn't seem to ever use my Pipeline.

**settings.py**

```
# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myspider.pipelines.MySpiderPipeline': 1, 
    #'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1, #I'VE TRIED BOTH <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}

FILES_STORE = 'downloaded_files/'
```

**items.py**

```
class MySpiderItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    file_name = scrapy.Field()
    file_urls = scrapy.Field()
    files = scrapy.Field()
```

**pipelines.py**

```
import os
import mimetypes
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline

class MyPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        print('THIS NEVER GET PRINTED') #<<<<<<<<<<<
        return [Request(x, meta={'file_name': item.get('file_name')}) for x in item.get(self.files_urls_field, [])]

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        media_guid = request.meta['file_name']
        print('THIS ALSO NEVER GET PRINTED') #<<<<<<<<<<<
        ### THE REST OF THIS FUNCTION IS THE SAME FROM PARENT CLASS ### #<<<<<<<<<<<
        if media_ext not in mimetypes.types_map:
            media_ext = ''
            media_type = mimetypes.guess_type(request.url)[0]
            if media_type:
                media_ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(media_type)
        return 'full/%s%s' % (media_guid, media_ext)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

**myspider.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from myspider.items import MySpiderItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'MySpider'

    def start_requests(self):
        start_url = 'https://www.page.com/data/'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=start_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        available_files = response.xpath('//div[@class="unit-body"]/li/a')
        for file in available_files:
            url = file.xpath('@href').get()
            loader = ItemLoader(item=MySpiderItem(), selector=file)
            loader.add_value('file_urls', response.urljoin(url))
            loader.add_value('file_name', url)
            yield loader.load_item()
```

If I use `scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline` in `settings.py` the files get downloaded as usual, which means they have a hash as filename. If I use `myspider.pipelines.MySpiderPipeline` **NO file is downloaded**, NONE of those prints get printed (so I can conclude that `MySpiderPipeline` is not beign called), but I believe I've done everything to enable it. What am I missing?

--

## EDIT - added logs:

```
2020-01-27 11:15:21 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: myspider)
2020-01-27 11:15:21 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.7.0, Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-01-27 11:15:21 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'myspider', 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 1200, 'LOG_FILE': 'output.log', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'myspider.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['myspider.spiders']}
2020-01-27 11:15:21 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 0ebe68b8aeac79b5
2020-01-27 11:15:21 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-01-27 11:15:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-01-27 11:15:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-01-27 11:15:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['myspider.pipelines.MyPipeline']
2020-01-27 11:15:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-01-27 11:15:22 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-01-27 11:15:22 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-01-27 11:15:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.page.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-01-27 11:15:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.page.com/data/> (referer: None)
2020-01-27 11:15:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.page.com/data/a/> (referer: https://www.page.com/data/)
2020-01-27 11:15:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.page.com/data/a/>

{'file_name': ['myfile_1'],
 'file_urls': ['https://www.page.com/cdd/myfile_1.csv']}
2020-01-27 11:15:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.page.com/data/a/>

{'file_name': ['myfile_2'],
 'file_urls': ['https://www.page.com/cdd/myfile_2.csv']}
2020-01-27 11:15:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.page.com/data/a/>

[... lots of the same prints as above (different files obviously) ...]

2020-01-27 11:15:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-01-27 11:15:25 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 5362,
 'downloader/request_count': 19,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 19,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 94335,
 'downloader/response_count': 19,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 18,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.999766,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 27, 14, 15, 25, 343255),
 'item_scraped_count': 541,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 560,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 19,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 18,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 18,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 18,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 18,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 27, 14, 15, 22, 343489)}
2020-01-27 11:15:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file). The beginning of the log should have all of the information about which pipelines are being enabled.

Comment: Sure, just edited the question to add the logs @Granitosaurus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked source code of [`FilesPipeline`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.8.0/scrapy/pipelines/files.py) class and it's "ancestor" - [`MediaPipeline`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.8.0/scrapy/pipelines/media.py) class.

There is significant difference between `process_item` method of `MediaPipeline` (used by `FilesPipeline`) and `process_item` method of your `MyPipeline` class:
[`MediaPipeline.process_item` source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.8.0/scrapy/pipelines/media.py#L77-L82):

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    info = self.spiderinfo
    requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))
    dlist = [self._process_request(r, info) for r in requests]
    dfd = DeferredList(dlist, consumeErrors=1)
    return dfd.addCallback(self.item_completed, item, info)
```

this method calls `get_media_requests` method and schedule new requests directly using `twisted` deferreds.

 While `process_item` method of your pipeline does nothing:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    return item
```

I recommend You to delete `process_item` from your pipeline code.
After that original `process_item` method from `MediaPipeline` class should call your modified `get_media_requests` method of your pipeline.. after that your overidden `file_path` method should be called.

Comment: That was it. The process_item was standard from scrapy, so I didn't even looked. Thanks!